# Lock script batch file

Tags: batch-file

Okay, so I have a lock script that locks my computer, but using alt + tab gets around this. Is there a way to stop this? Also, entering nothing and pressing enter gets around it too.

The code uses 2 windows, one to keep the window open when it is closed

```
@echo off
powershell -command "& { $x = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application; $x.minimizeall() }"
tskill explorer
tskill explorer
:a
start /w Lock.bat
goto a
```

and the other is the actual lock script:

```
@echo off
mode 35,10
cls
color a
title Locked by %username%
echo What is the password?
set /p password=
if %password%==password goto end
goto fail

:end
start explorer
exit

:fail
exit
```

Is there a way to stop these from happening?

### Edit

I solved the blank issue by using

```
If [%password%]==[] goto fail
```

Comment: Why don't you press [Win]+[L]?

Comment: Because that is blocked on my computer network.

Comment: This is an XY problem. What are you really trying to achieve? Pressing Ctrl+Alt+Entf and starting task manager will probably allow you to start Explorer again. Someone could also simply kill the CMD process which runs the batch file.

Comment: [Win]+[L] is the only key I know which is directly handled by the operating system and cannot be changed. It is designed to securly lock the PC. How can that possibly be blocked?

Comment: @ThomasW. Maybe by group policy.

Comment: you can try to create a for loop that will look for the explorer process and keep on killing it if the password field is blank.  Something like that.

Comment: Yeah, group policy also blocks task manager from being opened too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I dont know how to stop the spawning of the explorer process with the behavior outlined above, but here is a the kill wa

Main script:

```
@echo off
powershell -command "& { $x = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application; $x.minimizeall() }"
start /min kill_switch.bat
:a
start /w Lock.bat
goto a
```

Lock.bat:

```
@echo off
mode 35,10
cls
color a
title Locked by %username%
echo What is the password?
set /p password=
if %password%==password goto end
goto fail

:end
echo "start explorer">"%TEMP%\startex.trace"
exit

:fail
exit
```

kill_switch.bat:

```
@echo off

if exist "%TEMP%\startex.trace" del /q "%TEMP%\startex.trace"

:KILL_SWITCH
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe"') do (
    echo INFO: Killing PID %%a
    taskkill /PID %%a /F
)

timeout /t 5 >nul
if not exist "%TEMP%\startex.trace" (
    goto KILL_SWITCH
) else (
    del /q "%TEMP%\startex.trace"
)
```